# How to collapse/reduce the amount of factor levels

Tags: r

I need some help with reducing the amount of levels in my factor, I have a data set with a column Sqft_basement, when i use the levels function it returns every number that appears in that column, how would i change it so that the levels are either yes or no depending on if its greater than zero or equal to zero?

```
fbasement <- factor(House_Data$sqft_basement)
levels(fbasement)[levels(fbasement) > 0] <- "yes"
levels(fbasement)[levels(fbasement) <= 0] <- "no"
table(fbasement)



  fbasement
  no  yes 
  3677 2323
```

resulting in this.

I was wondering if there was a different way to do this as the method i used feels very crude.

Comment: Why do you need to convert it into a `factor`? Wouldn't a simple `fbasement 
 <- ifelse(House_Data$sqft_basement > 0, "yes", "no")` work ?

Comment: For the project i am doing the lecturer specified it to be stored as a factor variable

Answer (score 0):

Storing square foot numbers in a factor is a bad idea, but if that's how you got your data, you'll have to deal with it. However, you may have misunderstood your instructor – maybe he meant to say that the resulting yes/no information should be stored in a factor? That would make more sense.

Anyway, let's generate some data to play with:

```
foo <- factor(sample(0:10, 100, rep=TRUE))
```

Before anything else, I'd change back the data to be what it really is (numeric):

```
foo <- as.numeric(as.character(foo))
```

Now, I'd probably just go for a simple boolean result:

```
foo>0
```

If, for some reason you need "yes" and "no" instead, you can convert to that:

```
ifelse(foo>0, "yes", "no")
```

Another, potentially more elegant, approach would be using the cut function:

```
cut(foo, breaks=c(-Inf,0,Inf), labels=c("no", "yes"))
```